# Как скачать часть файла JS и получить его содержимое?

Tags: javascript, ajax, скорость

Доброе время суток.

Занимаюсь определением скорости сети, но столкнулся со следущим: при высокой скорости интернета файл скачивается быстро, но при низкой это может затянуться на долго. Как прервать ajax запрос и узнать, сколько байт файла скачалось?

UPD:

```
    function checkNetworkSpeed() {
        let start_time = new Date();
        let test_file_url = '/static/test_file?_=' + (+start_time);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: test_file_url,
            // timeout: 5000,
            success: function (data) {
                let finish_time = new Date(),
                    diff = (finish_time - start_time) / 1000;
                let size = data.length;
                window.page_stat.speed = (size / (diff || 1) / 1000).toFixed(2); // Kb/s
            },
        })
    }
```

Comment: как именно ты скачиваешь файл?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch-abort

Comment: @Grundy , Через $.ajax({type: 'get', ...}) .

Comment: @nörbörnën , я там был, нет информации о том, сколько данных было получено за время выполнения запроса.

Comment: вообще есть, но я понял о чем ты. может лучше взять xhr обычный? - он простой и управляемый, есть и прогресс, и abort

Comment: @nörbörnën я пробовал, но не понял (не получилось) как работает

Comment: я пробовал приостановить через let xhr = $.ajax({...}); xhr.abort(); но не смог получить размер данных

Comment: ммм, посмотрел подробную доку по указанным методам, спасибо, понял, буду разбираться. как будут результаты - отпишусь

Comment: @nörbörnën оформи как ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: @ZaArs блин, тут работы на минут 45 для качественного ответа (чтоб расписать с примерами на xhr, fetch, jquery)